# SQL join query result issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables one is Friends table and other table is user profile table (all user related information e.g. firstname, lastname etc) both has relation among them

Friend table (It has two entries for every user for e.g. the first two rows)

[image]

Now i want to display names of users from above table which will look like below

[image]

so in the output i want to remove duplicates which is not working for me
my query

```
select distinct u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName As UserName,
      (select distinct  firstname + ' ' + lastname from UserProfiles where id =   uw.friendid) as FriendName
       from UserFriends as uw left join userprofiles as u 
       on u.id = uw.userid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join `UserProfiles` twice on `UserFriends` since there are two columns are dependent on it.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        f.FirstName + ' ' + f.LastName FriendName,
        u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName UserName
FROM    UserFriends a
        INNER JOIN UserProfiles f
            ON a.FriendID = f.ID
        INNER JOIN UserProfiles u
            ON a.UserID = u.ID
        INNER JOIN UserFriends dup
            ON a.FriendID = dup.UserID 
                AND dup.FriendID = a.UserID 
                AND a.ID > dup.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cae6d/5)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this is still giving me duplicates

Comment: Looking at your desired result, where is the value of `ID` coming from?

Comment: That is just normal Unique Id

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41541/discussion-between-user1037747-and----)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have to use CTE to eliminate the duplicates from the beggining(that can be done by self joining the table). I have managed to reproduce your scenario, so if you adjust the query a bit, you will be able to obtain the desired result

```
with cte as
(select 
t1.id as a_id
,t1.friendID as a_friendID
 ,t1.userID as a_userID
,t2.id as b_id
,t2.friendID as b_friendID
,t2.userID as b_userID
 from #temp t1
 left join #user t2 on t1.id+1=t2.id
 ),
 cte2 as

 select 
 a_id
,a_userID
,a_friendID
 from cte t1
 where a_friendID = (select b_friendID from cte t2 where t2.b_id= t1.b_id-1)
 )


select firstname+ ' '+lastname as FriendName
,firstname+ ' '+lastname as UserName 
from cte2 uw
left join   UserProfiles u on uw.a_userID=u.ID and uw.a_friendID=u.id
```